# Escaping in sed command

Tags: sed, escape-characters

I'm trying to replace all instances of `$timestamp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['Timestamp']);` with `$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` in all files under `/home/user/public_html/`

I have tried many variations of the below command but can't seem to get the escaping right!

```
find /home/user/public_html/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\$timestamp = mysqli_real_escape_string(\$db_conx, \$_POST['\''Timestamp'\'']);/\$timestamp = date(\"Y-m-d H:i:s\");/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, all the other threads I could find on this were hard to follow but I was able to get it thanks to that thread

Answer (score 0):

I got it thanks to @phk

```
find /home1/user/public_html/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\$timestamp = mysqli_real_escape_string(\$db_conx, \$_POST\['\''Timestamp'\''\]);/\$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");/g'
```

Comment: As often (if not always), `-print0` and `xargs -0` are useless and the command can be replaced by  `find /home1/user/public_html/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\$timestamp = mysqli_real_escape_string(\$db_conx, \$_POST\['\''Timestamp'\''\]);/\$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");/g' {} +`